# Get specific elements from ndarray of ndarrays with shape (n,)

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Given the ndarray:

```
A = np.array([np.array([1], dtype='f'), 
              np.array([2, 3], dtype='f'), 
              np.array([4, 5], dtype='f'),
              np.array([6], dtype='f'), 
              np.array([7, 8, 9], dtype='f')])
```

which displays as:

```
A
array([array([ 1.], dtype=float32), array([ 2.,  3.], dtype=float32),
   array([ 4.,  5.], dtype=float32), array([ 6.], dtype=float32),
   array([ 7.,  8.,  9.], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to create a new array from the first elements of each "sub-array" of A. To show you what I mean, below is some code creating the array that I want using a loop. I would like to achieve the same thing but as efficiently as possible, since my array A is quite large (~50000 entries) and I need to do the operation many times.

```
B = np.zeros(len(A))
for i, val in enumerate(A):
    B[i] = val[0]
B
array([ 1.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  7.])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that concatenates all elements into an `1D` array and then select the first elements by `linear-indexing`. The implementation would look like this -

```
lens = np.array([len(item) for item in A])
out = np.concatenate(A)[np.append(0,lens[:-1].cumsum())]
```

The bottleneck would be with the concatenation part, but that might be offsetted if there are huge number of elements with small lengths. So, the efficiency would depend on the format of the input array.

Comment: Thanks, this is the fastest of the two answers. Still not as fast as I would like, but definitely an improvement over my naive approach.

Comment: @jmc Glad to hear that it's an improvement over the original approach, awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transforming your original jagged array of arrays into a single masked array:

```
B = np.ma.masked_all((len(A), max(map(len, A))))

for ii, row in enumerate(A):
    B[ii,:len(row)] = row
```

Now you have:

```
[[1.0 -- --]
 [2.0 3.0 --]
 [4.0 5.0 --]
 [6.0 -- --]
 [7.0 8.0 9.0]]
```

And you can get the first column this way:

```
B[:,0].data
```